# bootstrap dropdown bubble align right (not push-right)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have cart in my top menu, using `push-right` and my problem is that the dropdown bubble falls out of the page. I am trying to align the bubble right, so that it right-aligns with 'click'

like this

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="cart pull-right">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CLICK</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
       STUFF
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to put into http://jsfiddle.net to show others what you have.

Comment: have you tried `right:0;` on dropdown?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5+** (Update June 2022)

`dropdown-menu-right` has been replaced with `dropdown-menu-end`

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    STUFF
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

**Bootstrap 3.1+**

Adding the class .dropdown-menu-right to the same div containing the class dropdown-menu:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    STUFF
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment

**Bootstrap 2.3 & 3.0**

Add the class .pull-right to the same div containing the class dropdown-menu

```
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    STUFF
</div>
```

This seems to work for me using bootstrap 3.0

Comment: Since v3.1.0 you can use *dropdown-menu-right*.

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/dropdowns.less#L135

Answer (score 20):

This can be solved with the bootstrap class `dropdown-menu-right`  with `dropdown-menu` that is specifically for this problem that uses the css properties `right: 0;` and `left: auto;` to right align it.

This solution is working for me.

Source - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup (go to developer tools for this)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution (Bootstrap 3.3.7). Just make sure you add the class `dropdown-menu-right` to the `ul` that contains the menu options (not to the button)

Answer (score 9):

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
```

This is still working in boostrap 4.2.1 :)

Answer (score 6):

in `bootstrap v 3.1.0` the answer to this question is different.

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ratoa49d/)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-menu-right">
       STUFF
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

ok got it!

`position:relative;left:0` on `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`