# Align Bootstrap dropdown to the right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap dropdowns:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

As you can see, once a dropdown is open, it's always aligns to the left. Is there a way to make it align to the right? 
(I can do it individually per dropdown by setting `.dropdown-menu {left: [something];`), but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap dropdown bubble align right (not push-right)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892351/bootstrap-dropdown-bubble-align-right-not-push-right)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment

Comment: @lmgonzalves The link you provided may be a duplicate but the accepted answer is deprecated now (see the link in my previous comment).

Comment: But there is a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892351/bootstrap-dropdown-bubble-align-right-not-push-right#comment36251011_20262072) saying that. Anyway the best source is Bootstrap site.

Comment: ^ Yep, I didn't see it in there - I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like pull-right is deprecated, `.dropdown-menu-right` is a way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `pull-right` or `pull-menu-right` (`bootstrap v3.1. upwards`)class depending on what version of bootstrap you are running.

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ratoa49d/)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    your dropdown 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use its class : **.pull-right**

For I. E.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item 02</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item 03</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item 04</a></li>
</ul>
```