# Sub drop down menu is not going in right direction

Tags: html, css

I am creating a sub dropdown and I want to make it open in the right direction but it is opening at the same position. When I am using `left: 100%` it is opening in the left direction and working correctly but not when using the right direction.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-70px;">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-hand-o-left" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px;"></i>
                Edit-file
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 0px;Right:100%;text-align:right;">
                <li>action</li>
                <li> sub action</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown menu is not opening in the right direction.

```
<style>right: 100%</style>
```

Comment: Remove padding-right:10px

Comment: please provide working code at some external site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892351/bootstrap-dropdown-bubble-align-right-not-push-right